# blazor how to use jquery library

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

in the blazor input binding doesn't work when i use jquery input mask or any plugins like date picker or select 2

im using this library for input mask
https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use JavaScript libraries with Blazor you must use JavaScript Interop. Blazor needs to be in control of the DOM in order to work correctly. Attempting to use JavaScript without Blazors knowledge will cause lots of issues.

I would suggest reading up about JavaScript Interop on the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0).